# Email is not showing google Roboto Fonts in Microsoft Outlook 2016

Tags: outlook-2016, roboto

Client are not able to get mail in Roboto font format in Microsoft Outlook 2016.

As we trigger Email from our website which contain all Roboto font classes in HTML but In client outlook-2016, Email is not showing in Roboto font format its simply change in normal fonts format.

Is there any setting in Outlook2016 where we can check what the font setting client have for **EMAIL BODY** in read/Incoming mail section. ( Note- i have to check the font of **Email body**)

Note - Google Roboto font is enable in Client VM.
I already checked - file->option->mail->Stationery and fonts ->New Email Message -fonts.-- all are having default setting.